# Iterator becomes nvalid

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

ALL,

```
std::vector<string>::iterator it;
string orig;
bool found = false;
for( it = vec.begin(); it < vec.end() && !found; it++ )
{
    if( ... )
    {
        found = true;
        orig = (*it);
    }
}
```

After I get out of the loop the iterator become invalid even if I have `found = true`.

How do I keep the iterator? I need it for later processing..

MSVC 2017, Windows 8.1

TIA!!!

Comment: `break` out of the loop to avoid `it++`.  or assign `it` to another variable of type `std::vector<string>::iterator`.

Comment: You might consider using [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) rather than rolling your own loop.

Comment: Tia thanks you for the shout-out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decrement `it` in the case you found it, to undo the final `it++` that you don't want.

```
if (found) it--;
```

Or you could use `std::find_if`, where `...` uses `value` instead of `*it`.

```
auto it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](std::string & value) ( return value.find("abc"); });
auto found = it != vec.end();
auto orig = *it;
```

Comment: Note that `it--` restricts you to bidirectional iterators, while `find_if` will work with any input iterator (a much broader category). If you're only doing this with vectors, it doesn't matter, but if you're writing a generic function, it's worth keeping in mind.

Comment: @Caleth, thank you. I used `find_if`` method and it works.